# Need to use lock or not?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

```
class Session(list) :

        def __init__(self, session_file, laps_sound_file, end_sound_file, autoparse=True) :

            self.session_file = session_file
            self.laps_sound_file = laps_sound_file
            self.end_sound_file = end_sound_file

            self.cont_flag = threading.Event()
            self.cont_flag.set()

            if autoparse : self.parse()

        def start(self) :

            print("Entrainement Are going to start in : 10 sec\n" * 10)
            time.sleep(10)

            for action in self :

                if not self.cont_flag.is_set() :
                    print('pause\n' * 10)
                    self.cont_flag.wait()

                os.system('cls')

                print(str(action) * 10)
                winsound.PlaySound(self.laps_sound_file.split('.')[0], winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                time.sleep(action.time)

            winsound.PlaySound(self.end_sound_file.split('.')[0], winsound.SND_FILENAME)

        def pause(self) :
            self.cont_flag.clear()

        def cont_session(self) :
            self.cont_flag.set()
```

i have 2 thread in my programm, the first thread is waiting console input and the second thread is executing **start** methode of class **Session**

the first thread is acting like a control panel on the session thread, there is the code :

```
while 1 :
    command = input("enter you're command : ").strip().lower()

if command == 'exit' :
    break
elif command == 'pause' :
    sess.pause()
elif command == 'continue' :
    sess.cont_session()
else : print('invalide command, please retry')
```

so i want to know if i must use a lock between :

```
if not self.cont_flag.is_set() :
            print('pause\n' * 10)
            self.cont_flag.wait()
```

and

```
def pause(self) :
        self.cont_flag.clear()
```

Comment: Subclassing `list` is never helpful. It often leads to unexpected, undefined behavior.

Comment: its better then to implement actions in a list inside the Session class?

Comment: Yes, that would be typical.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a lock here. The whole point of an `Event` is that it's a synchronized flag.

---

That being said, your code has a race, and a lock won't help it—but it might be what you want anyway.

In this code:

```
if not self.cont_flag.is_set() :
    print('pause\n' * 10)
    self.cont_flag.wait()
```

… it is perfectly possible for the flag to be set and then cleared again between the `is_set` and the `wait`. In that case, you'll end up waiting until the flag is once again set.

But, unless you want to guarantee that the loop runs at least once for every continue (no matter how quickly you re-pause), or that "Pause" always gets printed out for each pause (no matter how quickly you re-continue and re-pause), that may be what you wanted to happen.

---

If you want to eliminate that race, you probably want a `Condition` and a regular bool variable, not an `Event`. While events are very simple, they're also very hard to compose into anything less simple…